# DirectX vs OpenGL

Tags: graphics, wine, opengl

We can run `DirectX` by using wine and `OpenGL` natively. So questions is:

- What is the exact version of `OpenGL` equivalent to `DirectX` (ex. 11, 12 etc) can we compare like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.

"We already know Ubuntu support `DirectX` by using wine and `OpenGL` natively."

This statement is **so** wrong on so many levels. Do you even understand what DirectX **is**?

In simple terms DirectX is a collection of libraries (*.dlls mostly), that serve to allow a developer easy access to Windows's lower level graphics, network and audio systems (maybe others too, never developed much with dx).

DirectX is basically something that allows a convenience layer so you can do things like "load and apply texture" instead of having to read every byte of color value from your jpg/png/whatever and draw them between 3 or more points on the screen based on some "geometry logic" because that would significantly harden the task of developing multimedia applications.

This means that Ubuntu does not support DirectX in any way. For that matter nothing really supports DirectX beyond Windows (and maybe [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) though I've never tested that).

**But I can run `<insert whatever game here>` on wine!**

Yes. Yes you can but that does not mean that **Ubuntu** supports your game. It means that **wine** does.

Wine is a "compatibility layer" for Windows stuff. It basically converts and resolves calls recursively so that at the end some other library will do something similar to what the original call would have done. This naturally requires intricate understanding of what the original call would do on the original system (Windows), hence some things get developed only slowly if at all in wine (like DX11 support, or the supposed Pulse driver).

So the above should answer your **third** question, but basically:

"Yes we do and it **is** wine."

From this you can see that your **first** question is kinda nonsensical since DX intends to focus on far more things than OpenGL.

As for the **second** question:

If we only consider the graphics part of of DX then I found OpenGL a bit more detailed (maybe even a bit convoluted) but ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics on Linux is almost exclusively implemented using the X windows system. Supporting OpenGL on Linux involves using GLX extensions to the X Server. So it depends on which GPU you are using.

It is supported by -

1. AMD/ATI
2. Intel
3. Nvidia
4. S3 Graphics
5. Nvidia HOWTO (old).

Latest version of OpenGL is **OpenGL 4.5**. To check your compatibility or for more information you can refer to this link -

[Platform specifics: Linux](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Platform_specifics:_Linux)

If you have OpenGL installed, you can get information about version that you are using by typing this command in terminal -

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

### Compare both API

I don't know much about DirectX but I can tell you advantages of using OpenGL-

1. Although Microsoft has worked hard on DirectX 10 and 11 (latest version), and they're now as fast as OpenGL, and support almost as many features as it could yet OpenGL has faster draw calls than DirectX according to [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl) and it has first access to new GPU features via [vendor extensions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extension).
2. Since OpenGL is a cross-platform application, it runs efficiently on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: I'm fairly sure DX12 is the latest as of 2015-09-30 and not DX11. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX)